# Using collection in several threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

How I can update the collection which using in another thread?

Example, I have a Control.

```
    class MyControls : Control
    {
    list<Car> cars;

     private void MyControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
          foreach(var car in cars)
          {
             // draw car
          }
     }

     private BtnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         LoadCarsFromDB(cars);
     }
    }
```

When call LoaCarsFromDB sometimes happens exception:

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

How can I modify my code to work without errors and delays?

Comment: dont use `foreach`, use `for` or `while` instead

Comment: @Shekhar, hmm, is that good advice?

Comment: what is being used in your multi-thread.. timer.. ? also using a foreach is not the issue in my opinion .. since you are iterating over a collection using foreach would be the recommend approach in you case.. can you show all relevant code..? what does LoadCarsFromDB look like

Comment: you might want to consider a thread-safe collection.  There's a whole namespace for them

Comment: @Jodrell nope it is not, and therefore it is a comment , I even thought of adding that any exceptions raised should be ignored  :P

Comment: What would you like to happen if `cars` changes while its being enumerated? Or, would you rather it couldn't change mid paint?

Answer (score 3):

as @dcastro said,

> you'll get the same exception if the collection is modified while `ToList` is being executed

Use one of the Concurrent collections, like `ConcurrentBag<car>` instead of `List<car>`

---

The problem is that you typically cannot modify a IEnumerable when it is being foreach'ed. Exceptions exist for classes in System.Collections.Concurrent.

To avoid this, you can call `cars.ToList()` in the foreach. This will basically copy the cars collection to a new collection when the foreach is started. cars can then be modified, but the foreach will not see those changes.

Alternatively, you can look into using a ConcurrentBag instead of a Collection.

Comment: There are also thread-safe collections in .NET.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: or you could use `lock` or `AsyncLock`

Comment: @Jodrell You could use a lock, but System.Collections.Concurrent actually use locks internally and therefore abstract that away and keep your code less complex.

Comment: This does not solve the problem: you'll get the same exception if the collection is modified *while* `ToList` is being executed.

Comment: @kmc059000 And, technically, the collections under the Concurrent namespace don't lock internally - they're implemented using lock-free techniques, such as atomic CAS (compare-and-swap).

Comment: @kmc059000 I meant to inform, not to show you up :P But yeah, replacing his list with a thread-safe collection altogether is probably the "easiest" solution (given our limited knowledge of the overall design).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<T>` that you want to write to from across multiple threads, you will need to use a collection from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace as an intermediate object. The objects in the Concurrent namespace are thread safe.

I generally transfer my collection of objects from a `List<T>` to a `ConcurrentBag<T>` or a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Then when done with the multi-threaded processing a convert the collection back to a `List<T>`

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
var threadsafeCars = new ConcurrentBag<Car>(cars);

//perform thread operations

// return to cars list
cars = threadsafeCars.ToList<Car>();
```

The other common cause for the exception you are seeing is that you are adding or removing an object in the List while iterating over it with a `foreach` or some other iterator that uses an `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable` is not editable and throws that exception.